# How to open an executable from the selected file in a file list?

Tags: forms, visual-studio, dos

I am using visual basic for dos, on my form i have a file list, I need to know how to execute the selected file in the file list ex, .com,.bat or .exe

The file list name is "File1"

I am new to visual basic.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? can you approve it as a correct answer? upvote? something?

Comment: what version of visual basic do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This example is how to startt process with parameter:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

OpenMicrosoftWord("C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Office\Gears.docx")

End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Open the path parameter with Microsoft Word.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub OpenMicrosoftWord(ByVal f As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE"
    startInfo.Arguments = f
    Process.Start(startInfo)
    End Sub
End Module
```

generally you need to use the `Process.Start` Method and the parameter will be the file you want to launch